# Extracting data from a XML feed with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, api, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to extract data from a XML feed using simplexml_load_file. This is what I have now:

```
    <?php 
        $anobii = simplexml_load_file('http://www.anobii.com/rss_shelf?s=01fe251a6c442bbf8a');
        foreach ($anobii->entry as $anobiiinfo):
            $title=$anobiiinfo->rss->channel->item->title;
            $desc=$anobiiinfo->rss->channel->item->description;       
            echo "<span> ",$title,"</span><br><span> ",$desc,"</span>";
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

The problem is that I don't know the right separators to tell the script the portions it needs to extract (`rss->channel->item->title`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yous should follow the xml tree structure to get the individual items.

```
<?php 
        $feedUrl = 'http://www.anobii.com/rss_shelf?s=01fe251a6c442bbf8a';
        $rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
        $anobii = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);

        foreach ($anobii->channel->item as $anobiiinfo):
            $title=$anobiiinfo->title;
            $desc=$anobiiinfo->description;       
            echo "<span> ",$title,"</span> <br/> <span> ",$desc,"</span>";
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! :D
It works!

Latest question: do you thing it's better/faster to use this method (file_get_contents) or the WordPress built in function fetch_feed (based on SimplePie)?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Thanks again! :)

Comment: I would prefer to use the fetch_feed, that should be better than using the rs URL to get the feed.